# Can't run executable after deploying WinForms CefSharp project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deployment, cefsharp

I have this rather simple WinForms CefSharp project. I can run it from Visual Studio 2015 just fine, but when I build the project, the final .exe generated by VS doesn't do anything, and by that I mean that after double clicking it, nothing will show up, literally nothing. No errors messages on error.log either.

I've read the [CefSharp FAQ](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions) and I've seen which files I should include for the redistribution.

This is how the executable folder looks like:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

Changing the VS version.

Messing around with the manifest file.

Tried to run the executable in another computer, with the same results.

Suggested by @amaitland, I tried to build and run the minimal example and the same thing happened, the cursor keeps on "Loading" but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you done the basics like check the `Event Viewer`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I've checked the Event Viewer, but nothing about this is there. I checked every Windows Logs and every App and Services Logs but SQLServerData ones.

Comment: I'd be using `Process Monitor` to see what's going on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx you'll have to google for more details if you require them